# Vegeta Load Testing: different body for each POST request in the attack

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, vegeta

Is there a way to change the json body in vegeta Post request load tests in vegeta.

I want to send a request with a different parameter in the json body for each of the requests. for example if I have

```
POST https://endpoint.com/createNew
@/targets/data.json
```

and data.json looks like

```
{
   "id": 1234
}
```

What is the best way to make it so we have different request data for each of the requests in the attack?

Answer (score 13):

I needed to do something similiar and decided to use the vegeta lib rather than cli for this which allows me to control the HTTP requests

So you need to write your own function which return a `vegeta.Targeter`

```
func NewCustomTargeter() vegeta.Targeter {
    return func(tgt *vegeta.Target) error {
        if tgt == nil {
            return vegeta.ErrNilTarget
        }

        tgt.Method = "POST"

        tgt.URL = "https://endpoint.com/createNew"

        rand := generateFourDigitRandom()

        payload := '{ "id":"`+rand+ `" } `
        tgt.Body = []byte(payload)
        return nil
    }
}
```

and use this function in the main function like this

```
    targeter := NewCustomTargeter()
    attacker := vegeta.NewAttacker()
    var metrics vegeta.Metrics
    for res := range attacker.Attack(targeter, rate, duration, "Load Test") {
        metrics.Add(res)
    }
    metrics.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%+v  \n", metrics)
```

Answer (score 2):

On Jul 10, 2018, [vegeta#PR300](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/pull/300) introduced the `-format=json` option. Here is the [vegeta README](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta#-format) description:

> The JSON format makes integration with programs that produce targets
>   dynamically easier. Each target is one JSON object in its own line.
>   The method and url fields are required. If present, the body field
>   must be base64 encoded. The generated JSON Schema defines the format
>   in detail.

And their provided example:

```
jq -ncM '{method: "GET", url: "http://goku", body: "Punch!" | @base64, header: {"Content-Type": ["text/plain"]}}' |
  vegeta attack -format=json -rate=100 | vegeta encode
```

Answer (score -7):

If you have multiple files under `targets` folder and would like to use them all in your load test I would suggest the following configuration:

1. [Install Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin using JMeter Plugins Manager

   [image: JMeter Directory Listing Config Installation]
2. Configure it to point to your `targets` folder:

   [image: Directory Listing Config - configuration]
3. In your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function like:

   ```
   ${__FileToString(${filename},,)}
   ```

   [image: Using file in request body]
4. When you run your test it will pick up the next file from `targets` directory and use its contents as the request body

   [image: JMeter Directory Listing Config in Action]